# How to tell Bazaar that a file is binary

Tags: bazaar

This is to avoid having some **<<<** or some **>>>** in that file if there are conflicts.

If there is a conflict, I just want a message telling me there is a conflict and bazaar should not mess with the file.

With subversion, you can modify the **svn:mime-type** property. But I don't know if Bazaar have this feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [reference](http://doc.bazaar-vcs.org/bzr.dev/en/user-reference/bzr_man.html#end-of-line-conversion) says that there is no explicit way of telling so far:

> Bazaar currently relies of [sic] content analysis to detect binary files for commands like diff. In the future, a `binary = true` rule may be added but it is not supported yet.

Answer (score 2):

It is annoying, but you still have the .BASE, .OTHER and .THIS files which are unchanged, you just replace the altered file with the one you need.
Can be scripted, I suppose.